# How to check if all siblings (including selected) are checked with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get only siblings of selected element but can't find a proper method for this or a way to achieve it. I always get the whole tree with find() method and with children() I can't get it to work.

This clicking should work like a checkbox tree:

If you click parent all children should be clicked and if you uncheck parent, all children must be unchecked.

But the thing that doesn't work is if you check a checkbox and all siblings are not clicked then the parent must indeterminate!

And also parent above must be undeterminate.

So what I actually need is to get the parent of selected checkbox and then collect the children and check if they all are checked. If yes then set parent as checked if not then parent must be indeterminate. But the problem is that jquery goes to deep.... and i need only the first children, and not everything underneath.

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input.parent_cat_0', function() {
  var mainPermission = $(this);
  var mainPermissionChildren = mainPermission.parent().find('input:checkbox');
  if (mainPermission.is(':checked')) {
    mainPermissionChildren.each(function() {
      this.indeterminate = false;
      this.checked = true;
    });
  } else {
    mainPermissionChildren.each(function() {
      this.indeterminate = false;
      this.checked = false;
      $(this).removeClass("displayNone").next("img.tick").remove();
    });
  }
});

$(document).on('change', 'input.docPermission:not(.parent_cat_0)', function() {
  var selected = $(this);
  var liParents = selected.parents('li');
  var allCheckboxes = liParents.find('input:checkbox');
  var childrenOfSelected = selected.parent().find('input:checkbox');
  var upperParents = $(allCheckboxes).not(childrenOfSelected).get();

  if (selected.is(':checked')) {
    childrenOfSelected.prop('indeterminate', false);
    childrenOfSelected.prop('checked', true);

    //console.log('Total upper parents:', upperParents.length);

    $(upperParents).each(function (i,e) {
      // HOW TO GET ONLY FIRST SIBLINGS
      // For example if you click on Form 1
      // you should get only (Form 1a, Form 1b, Form 1c)
      // but NOT 'Form 1aa'
      //console.log($(e));
    });

  } else {
    childrenOfSelected.prop('indeterminate', false);
    childrenOfSelected.prop('checked', false);
  }


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="main">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cat_52" class="docPermission  parent_cat_0" name="localPerm[]">
  <label class="strong" for="cat_52">Forms</label>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cat_53" class="docPermission  parent_cat_52" name="localPerm[]">
      <label class="strong" for="cat_53">Form 1</label>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="cat_55" class="docPermission  parent_cat_53" name="localPerm[]">
          <label class="strong" for="cat_55">Form 1a</label>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <input type="checkbox" id="cat_56" class="docPermission  parent_cat_55" name="localPerm[]">
              <label class="strong" for="cat_56">Form 1aa</label>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="main">
          <input type="checkbox" id="doc_80" class="docPermission  parent_cat_53" name="localPerm[]">
          <label for="doc_80">Form 1b</label>
        </li>
        <li class="main">
          <input type="checkbox" id="doc_82" class="docPermission  parent_cat_53" name="localPerm[]">
          <label for="doc_82">Form 1c</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cat_54" class="docPermission  parent_cat_52" name="localPerm[]">
      <label class="strong" for="cat_54">Form 2</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: First can we clarify something, in your code you write `if you click on Form 1 you should get only (Form 1a, Form 1b, Form 1c)` but aint form 1a, 1b, 1c not a child of form 1?

Comment: Your code has almost 50 lines, how would we guess what `find()` you want to fix? There is a lot of them..

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown The commented part is important.

Comment: Are you able to dynamically add an attribute to the elements to identify them? You could just do something like `data-scope="level1"` (where the numbers increase each level deep). Then it's simply grabbing the `data-scope` and selecting the element that was clicked and then selecting the next level up (`level + 1`)

Comment: You want `$(this).siblings().first()` ?

Comment: this gets the siblings true... but now i realized I need all children.... the point is to check if all siblings are checked! including himself

Comment: the function `children()` gets all direct children. `find()` gets all ancestors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `siblings()` and `andSelf()`

```js
$(document).on('change', 'input:checkbox', function(e) {
  const $this = $(this);

  if (!e.isTrigger) {
    $this
      .siblings('ul')
      .find('input:checkbox')
      .prop('checked', this.checked);
  }

  const $children = $this.parent('li').siblings().addBack();
  const $ckb = $children.find('> input:checkbox');

  const total = $ckb.length;
  const checked = $ckb.filter(':checked').length;
  const indeter = $ckb.filter(function() {
    return this.indeterminate;
  }).length;

  $this
    .parents('ul:first')
    .siblings('input:checkbox')
    .prop({
      checked: checked === total,
      indeterminate: indeter > 0 || (checked > 0 && checked < total)
     })
    .trigger('change')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li class="main">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat_52" class="docPermission  parent_cat_0" name="localPerm[]">
    <label class="strong" for="cat_52">Forms</label>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cat_53" class="docPermission  parent_cat_52" name="localPerm[]">
        <label class="strong" for="cat_53">Form 1</label>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cat_55" class="docPermission  parent_cat_53" name="localPerm[]">
            <label class="strong" for="cat_55">Form 1a</label>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="cat_56" class="docPermission  parent_cat_55" name="localPerm[]">
                <label class="strong" for="cat_56">Form 1aa</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="main">
            <input type="checkbox" id="doc_80" class="docPermission  parent_cat_53" name="localPerm[]">
            <label for="doc_80">Form 1b</label>
          </li>
          <li class="main">
            <input type="checkbox" id="doc_82" class="docPermission  parent_cat_53" name="localPerm[]">
            <label for="doc_82">Form 1c</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cat_54" class="docPermission  parent_cat_52" name="localPerm[]">
        <label class="strong" for="cat_54">Form 2</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works 90% there is only one more thing.... when you click the parent all children should be checked also. But I think I can solve this.... anyway thank you very much.

Comment: Improved your code to account for `indeterminate` recursion to parents.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan `> 0` in `indeterminate` condition can be neglected. Am I right?

Comment: @AswinKumar Exactly. One could write the entirety as `indeter || checked && checked < total`. Depends on how readable you want it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of relying on `SomeParentCheckbox.trigger('change')`
**we could traverse parent groups recursively**

- *On checkbox change*, handle descendant checkboxes (any depth), set `checked` state same as the triggered one.
- *On checkbox change*, recursively traverse parents to set `checked` or `indeterminate` attributes states

```js
function handleDocPermParent(ckb) {
  // Get group element: (Ideally we would have a 'group' class, but sadly we don't, so let's go tricky for known common selectors)
  const $group = $(ckb).closest('ul');
  const $par   = $group.closest('li');
  
  if (!$par.length) return; // No parent? Recursion job done!
  
  const $par_ckb = $par.find(docPermClass).first(); // Find parent's main checkbox
  const $group_ckb = $group.children('li').children(docPermClass); // Collect all group's checkboxes
  
  const tot = $group_ckb.length; // How many checkboxes?
  const tot_checked = $group_ckb.filter(':checked').length; // How many siblings are checked?
  const tot_indeter = $group_ckb.filter((i, e) => e.indeterminate).length; // How many siblings are indeterminate?
  
  $par_ckb.prop({ // Finally set parent's main checkbox state:
    checked: tot_checked === tot,
    indeterminate: tot_indeter || tot_checked && tot_checked < tot
  });
  
  handleDocPermParent($par_ckb[0]); // Recursively iterate to outer parent
}

const docPermClass = '.docPermission';
const $docPerm = $(docPermClass);

$docPerm.on('change', function (evt) {
  const $ch = $(this).parent().find(docPermClass).not(this);
  $ch.prop({checked: this.checked}); // Handle inner checkboxes (in all childrens, any depth) explicitly:
  handleDocPermParent(this); // Handle parents recursively (from inner to outer) implicitly:
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="main">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cat_52" class="docPermission  parent_cat_0" name="localPerm[]">
    <label class="strong" for="cat_52">Forms</label>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cat_53" class="docPermission  parent_cat_52" name="localPerm[]">
        <label class="strong" for="cat_53">Form 1</label>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cat_55" class="docPermission  parent_cat_53" name="localPerm[]">
            <label class="strong" for="cat_55">Form 1a</label>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="cat_56" class="docPermission  parent_cat_55" name="localPerm[]">
                <label class="strong" for="cat_56">Form 1aa</label>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="main">
            <input type="checkbox" id="doc_80" class="docPermission  parent_cat_53" name="localPerm[]">
            <label for="doc_80">Form 1b</label>
          </li>
          <li class="main">
            <input type="checkbox" id="doc_82" class="docPermission  parent_cat_53" name="localPerm[]">
            <label for="doc_82">Form 1c</label>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="cat_54" class="docPermission  parent_cat_52" name="localPerm[]">
        <label class="strong" for="cat_54">Form 2</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```